# Why can't I hear voice chat in my headset?

Tags: ps4, voice-chat

I own a set of A10 headphones and the audio output works perfectly. The issue is actually with voice chat. For some reason when I plug in my headset there is no chat audio. I have searched all over my PS4 settings and have found nothing wrong. I am also able to use a pair of cheap earbuds with a microphone and the chat audio comes through fine. What could be the problem? Plugged into a phone I can hear music and game audio, but cannot hear people over the phone. Though I can't hear them, my friends can still hear me.

Answer (score 1):

Try these steps this should let you balance the game and chat audio I had to do something similar with a pair of hypercloud headphones

1. Go into your settings menu
2. Then Devices
3. Audio devices
4. For the input and output devices select the wired headset
5. Go back to audio devices and select the "output to headphones" option
6. Make sure that option is set to "All Audio"
7. Go into your active game.  You cannot adjust the correct settings from the settings menu.
8. Hold down the PS button on your controller until the options menu appears.
9. At the top of the options menu you should see an icon for the program you are running and a volume bar.  Click that option
10. You should see a menu that allows you to adjust the game volume as well as chat volume.  Simply adjust the game/chat balance per your preference.

Answer (score -2):

I finally fixed mine by going INTO THE APP I was playing (Apex Legends) and I saw that my MASTER VOLUME and GAME EFFECTS were both at 100%.  I turned them down to 50% and i could finally hear my voice. HOORAY!